# segmentation fault linked-list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

please dont press the rep minus button so easily im new here- be nice please

i have slist.h implementing by slist.c

here is the slist.h

```
    #ifndef DBLLIST_H
    #define DBLLIST_H

    //! The definition of a double linked list node
        typedef struct dbllist_node
{
    void *data; // Pointer to data of this node
    struct dbllist_node *next; // Pointer to next node on list
    struct dbllist_node *prev; // Pointer to previous node on list
}dbllist_node_t;


//! The definition of a double linked list
struct dbllist
{
    dbllist_node_t *head; // Pointer to head of list
    dbllist_node_t *tail; // Pointer to tail of list
    unsigned int size; // The number of elements in the list
};

//! double linked list type
typedef struct dbllist dbllist_t;


// you have to use these macros, do not use the inner variables of the list!!
//! Macro to get the head node of a list l
#define dbllist_head(l) l->head
//! Macro to get the tail node of a list l
#define dbllist_tail(l) l->tail
//! Macro to get the size of a list l
#define dbllist_size(l) l->size
//! Macro to get the next node of l
#define dbllist_next(n) n->next
//! Macro to get the prev node of l
#define dbllist_prev(n) n->prev
//! Macro to get the data of node l
#define dbllist_data(n) n->data

//! Specifies whether dbllist_destroy should deallocate or not stored elements
typedef enum { DBLLIST_LEAVE_DATA = 0, DBLLIST_FREE_DATA } dbllist_destroy_t;

/** Initialize a double linked list
    \param list - the list to initialize */
void dbllist_init(dbllist_t *);

/** Destroy and de-allocate the memory hold by a list
    \param list - a pointer to an existing list
    \param dealloc flag that indicates whether stored data should also be de-allocated */
void dbllist_destroy(dbllist_t *,dbllist_destroy_t);


/** Append data to list (add as last node of the list)
    \param list - a pointer to a list
    \param data - the data to place in the list
    \return 0 on success, or -1 on failure */
int dbllist_append(dbllist_t *,void *);

/** Prepend data to list (add as first node of the list)
    \param list - a pointer to list
    \param data - the data to place in the list
    \return 0 on success, or -1 on failure
*/
int dbllist_prepend(dbllist_t *,void *);

/** \brief Remove the specific node from the list.
    \param to a pointer to the list
    \param pointer to the node that should be removed.
    \param dealloc flag that indicates whether to de-allocated the data in the node
    \return 0 on success, or -1 on failure
*/

int dbllist_remove(dbllist_t *, dbllist_node_t* ,dbllist_destroy_t);
#endif
```

and now the slist.c i wrote

my problem is when ever i call the destroy function im facing segmentation fault at the last node.. i can provide main that i wrote too.

```
    #include "slist.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void dbllist_init(dbllist_t *list)
    {   if(list != NULL)
        {
    dbllist_head(list) = NULL;
    dbllist_tail(list) = NULL;
    dbllist_size(list) = 0;
        }
    }

    int dbllist_append(dbllist_t *list,void *data)
    {
    dbllist_node_t *temp = (dbllist_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(dbllist_node_t));

    if(temp == NULL)
    return -1;
    dbllist_data(temp) = data;
    if(list!=NULL)
{
    if(dbllist_head(list) == NULL)
    {
        //dbllist_next(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_prev(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_head(list) = temp;
        dbllist_tail(list) = temp;
        dbllist_size(list)++;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dbllist_next(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_prev(temp) = dbllist_tail(list);
        dbllist_next(dbllist_tail(list)) = temp;
        dbllist_tail(list) = temp;
        dbllist_size(list)++;
        return 0;
    }
}
return -1;
    }

    int dbllist_prepend(dbllist_t *list,void *data)
    {
 dbllist_node_t *temp = (dbllist_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(dbllist_node_t));

if(temp == NULL)
    return -1;
dbllist_data(temp) = data;
if(list!=NULL)
{
    if(dbllist_head(list) == NULL)
    {
        //dbllist_next(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_prev(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_head(list) = temp;
        dbllist_tail(list) = temp;
        dbllist_size(list)++;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dbllist_next(temp) = dbllist_head(list) ;
        dbllist_prev(temp) = NULL;
        dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)) = temp;
        dbllist_head(list) = temp;
        dbllist_size(list)++;
        return 0;
    }
}
return -1;
    }
    /**
    int dbllist_remove(dbllist_t *list, dbllist_node_t* pointer,dbllist_destroy_t   dealloc)
    {
dbllist_node_t *temp = (dbllist_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(dbllist_node_t));

    if(temp == NULL)
        return -1;
    temp = dbllist_head(list);
if(list != NULL && pointer !=NULL)
{
    if(pointer == dbllist_head(list))
        {
            if(dealloc != DBLLIST_LEAVE_DATA)
                free(dbllist_data(pointer));
            dbllist_head(list) = NULL;
            dbllist_size(list) = 0;
            dbllist_tail(list) = NULL;
            free(dbllist_head(list));
            free(temp);
            return 0;
        }
    if(pointer == dbllist_tail(list))
        {
            dbllist_tail(list) = dbllist_prev(dbllist_tail(list)) ;
            dbllist_next(dbllist_tail(list)) = NULL;
            if(dealloc != DBLLIST_LEAVE_DATA)
                free(dbllist_data(pointer));
            free(temp);
            free(pointer);
            dbllist_size(list)--;
            return 0 ;
        }
    int tempSize = 1;
    for(temp = dbllist_next(temp) ; tempSize< dbllist_size(list); temp =       dbllist_next(temp),tempSize++)
        if(temp == pointer)
        {
            dbllist_next(dbllist_prev(temp)) = dbllist_next(temp);
            dbllist_prev(dbllist_next(temp)) = dbllist_prev(temp);
            if(dealloc != DBLLIST_LEAVE_DATA)
                free(dbllist_data(pointer));
            free(temp);
            free(pointer);
            dbllist_size(list)--;
            return 0;
        }

}
return -1;
    }
     */
    int dbllist_remove(dbllist_t *list, dbllist_node_t* pointer,dbllist_destroy_t dealloc)
    {
if(list == NULL || pointer == NULL )
    return -1;

//printf("%d \n",(int)dbllist_data(current));

if( pointer == dbllist_head(list))
{
    dbllist_head(list) = dbllist_next(dbllist_head(list));
    if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA)
        free(dbllist_data(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list))));
    free(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)));
    dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)) = NULL;
    dbllist_size(list)--;
    return 0;
}

if(pointer == dbllist_tail(list))
{
    dbllist_tail(list) = dbllist_prev(dbllist_tail(list));
    if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA)
        free(dbllist_data(dbllist_next(dbllist_tail(list))));
    free(dbllist_next(dbllist_tail(list)));
    dbllist_next(dbllist_tail(list)) = NULL;
    dbllist_size(list)--;
    return 0;
}


    //int i = 1;
    dbllist_node_t *current  = dbllist_next(dbllist_head(list));
    while(current)
    {
        if(current == pointer)
        {
            dbllist_next(dbllist_prev(current)) = dbllist_next(current) ;
            dbllist_prev(dbllist_next(current)) = dbllist_prev(current) ;
            dbllist_size(list)--;
            if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA)
                free(dbllist_data(current));
            free(current);
            current = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        current = dbllist_next(current);
    }
free(current);
return -1;
    } 

    void dbllist_destroy(dbllist_t *list ,dbllist_destroy_t dealloc)
    {
//dbllist_node_t *current = (dbllist_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(dbllist_node_t));
//dbllist_node_t *temp = (dbllist_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(dbllist_node_t));


while (dbllist_head(list) != NULL)
{
    //dbllist_node_t *current;
    dbllist_node_t *temp ;

    temp = dbllist_tail(list);
        while(temp)
        {
            dbllist_remove(list,temp , dealloc);
            printf("in\n");
            temp = dbllist_tail(list);
            printf("out \n");
        }
    //temp = dbllist_head(list);
    //dbllist_remove(list,temp , dealloc);
    //free(temp);
}
//free(current);
//free(temp);

    }
```

can someone understand the error and explain to me how to fix it

im trying over a feew hours now without success

Comment: Have you tried using a debugging memory allocator (like http://dmalloc.com/) to see if it spots the problem?

Comment: i use valgrind but didnt detect where im wrong
was easier if it was windows but making us write in fedora

Comment: you can use `eclipse`(though rather big) in fedora if you want an IDE

Comment: i use eclipse in fedora just to write and live correction but it doesnt compile.
everything works - the list get destroyed but with a segmentation fault

Comment: It does not compile? How are you getting it to Seg Fault then?

Comment: it does compile but i meant eclipse dont have that feature in fedora at least from what i know

Comment: By last node, do you mean the Tail or the Head?

Comment: the head. i reverse deleting.

Comment: ALWAYS parenthesize maco arguments before referring them: `#define dbllist_head(l) l->head` -->> `#define dbllist_head(l) (l)->head`. (these dubious macros might not be the cause of the error, but they could cause  new errors in the future)

Comment: @wildplasser - it is not the problem for sure but if its causing problem then ill sue my teacher lol

Comment: btw im open to changes in my destroy function- must use the remove function in it tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right answer is:

```
    if(!dbllist_next(dbllist_head(list)))
    {
        if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA )
            free(dbllist_data(dbllist_head(list)));
        free(dbllist_head(list));
        dbllist_head(list) = NULL;
        dbllist_size(list)--;
        return 0;
    }
```

add this before the head part in remove function

because of a null pointer exception i did when in the head of the list.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
if( pointer == dbllist_head(list))
{
    // After next line: list->head points to next node (could be null)
    dbllist_head(list) = dbllist_next(dbllist_head(list));
    if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA)
        // -- If head is now NULL, what happens below? --
        free(dbllist_data(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list))));
    free(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)));
    dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)) = NULL;
    dbllist_size(list)--;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would hit the Head case first, by definition and how the list is set up, it would not hit that tail case if the previous pointer was null as that would indicate it being the head.

Comment: if prev node is null that means its the head of the list- we wont be getting here . dont we?

Comment: btw - everything is working besides the destroy function ive checked it all very deeply.

Answer (score 0):

In your Remove function `dbllist_remove` the section that is for the head case(pun intended ;)) tries to free memory that is NULL and not allocated.

The arguments `free(dbllist_data(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list))))` AND `dbllist_data(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)))` will not work as you have already removed the next element as well as its pointers. It was freed earlier in your destroy function. So, you cannot rely on the previous pointer actually pointing to anything.

So, I would modify your `while` loop in the destroy function to wait until `head->next` is `null` and then simply delete it outside of the loop and not use the standard remove function. Or modify your head case to take into account when `head->next` is null.

Comment: well im not sure if i completely understand you - but wouldnt it effect my remove function when i delete the head or the tail too?

Comment: Your remove function does not work if it is removing a node from a list with only one element.

Comment: u r completely right my friend :):):):)
how do i change that?

Comment: In the remove case for when it is the `head` put in an `if` block that catches it when `head->next` is null. Put that before you try assigning anything to it. Then you can just delete it and the data in that block and return out without hitting the rest of the function. Not too many details as this is school related ;)

Comment: thats what i did but keep getting the seg fault

        if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA && dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list)))
   free(dbllist_data(dbllist_prev(dbllist_head(list))));

Comment: This does not happen JUST in the `DBLLIST_FREE_DATA` case. I thought that was clear in my answer. I will correct that it make it clearer.

Comment: ok i understand u and now i can remove if one lement only but still gets seg fault n destroy
'if(!dbllist_next(dbllist_head(list)))
  {
   if(dealloc == DBLLIST_FREE_DATA )
    free(dbllist_data(dbllist_head(list)));
   free(dbllist_head(list));
   dbllist_head(list) = NULL;
   return 0;
  }
'

Comment: perhaps i need to change also the tail case - maybe when i will delte the tail sometimes i cant get seg fault ,right?
any idea of leak i have here